# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library: /home/lib.so so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0 in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, c++, c, shared-libraries

i've managed to succesfully create an .php extension. I would like to move further. Insted of using the .cc that i want my .php to link with i would like to add the library.so.
When compiling i have this error.

how to solve it?

thx. appreciate

EDIT:

I succed to compile it. now i have this error:
 undefined symbol: _ZN3CarC1Ei. why?
it is true i did not add the .cc code. how to add iin config.m4 the .so file that contans the .h and .cc with which i wpuld like to work from php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to link with `libstdc++`. Or compile with `g++` instead of `gcc`, then `libstdc++` will be linked by default.

Comment: `_ZN3CarC1Ei` is mangled name of `Car::Car(int)`. Most likely you need to link it in also.

Comment: You need to add something like this to `config.m4`: `PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)`. Check [this link](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486)

Comment: the thing is that i don't want to add the car.cc in my config file. how to solve the problem without adding it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your extension has been compiled with g++ and you didn't linked the stdc++ library. You need to add something like this in config.m4:

```
  PHP_SUBST(YOUREXT_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(stdc++, "", YOUREXT_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

See here for an exemple: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/rar/trunk/config.m4?revision=299933&view=markup

Comment: try make clean, phpize again, configure again and make